# Accessing contents of /contents folder in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo, darknet

I want to train yolo on my own data and am using Google Colab but unable to edit .cfg files stored in contents folder. One solution I can think of is to fuse the google drive and installing darknet in gmail drive and running the program with drive as my working directory.

Comment: It seems like you've suggested your own answer :). Did you encounter any issues when trying using the Drive FUSE client as you describe?

Comment: Am yet to run it on drive but what I observed while installation is that, installing in contents folder was pretty quick with no hardware accelerator required but in order to install darknet on drive required me to switch to GPU hardware accelerator